# UIButton tag given in CellForRowAtIndexPath gives only last tag value in Custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, tableview

I have two `UIButton` in a `UITableViewCell` subclass, and in view controller class i have have its selector method, but on clicking on button it always gives the last tag value assigned inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";

    customCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    customCell.oneYear.tag = indexPath.row;

    customCell.threeYearButton.tag = indexPath.row + 50;
[customCell.oneYear addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(oneYearButtonAction)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[customCell.threeYearButton addTarget:self
                       action:@selector(threeYearButtonAction)
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[customCell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
```

It works fine if i use IBAction, but I have to use selector method, which gives above issue.

Kindly help.

Comment: Can you add your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method so we can get idea how you are setting your button tag?

Comment: yes, same here. Please add a snippet of your code

Comment: if i do it in didselectRow Method , selector method executes instead of didselectrow, so its not working

Comment: it should give me the different tag values for different buttons in different rows

Comment: Check with this for dequeing cell  - dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:

Comment: @karthikeyan would you please explain this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create new instance of your custom class with `cellForRowAtIndexPath` instead of that you are using the same instance `customCell`.

**Instead of this:**

```
customCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

**You need to create new object like this:**

```
CustomCellName *customCell = (CustomCellName*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

**Edit:** Instead of using `tag` with your cell's button action you can try like this way.

```
-(void)oneYearButtonAction:(UIButton*)sender {
     CGPoint center= sender.center; 
     CGPoint rootViewPoint = [sender.superview convertPoint:center toView:self.tableView];
     NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:rootViewPoint];
     CustomCellName *currentCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

Comment: I have one question, later on where do i get customCell object in selector method, are you suggesting to create multiple objects ?

Comment: please DeadPool

Comment: i am going to ask something stupid now, how do i call this method from selector method ?

Comment: in my question i am calling a method "@selector(oneYearButtonAction)"
Now you have added an argument sender, How do i call it

Comment: @ios_Dev Change you selector to  `action:@selector(oneYearButtonAction:)` like this same goes for `threeYearButtonAction`

Comment: @ios_Dev Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 2):

You have declared the cell out of the `cellForRow` method. If you do this your cell object will contains the last object thats why your button always have last tag.

> Solution

Declare your object for cell like this in `cellForRow`

```
  MyCustomCell *customCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; //what ever your class name be I am says MyCustomCell.
```

**NOTE:**   If you want to use cell object in any other method then there will be lots of other properties are available.

**HOW TO GET CELL OBJECT IN BUTTON ACTION METHOD**

```
- (IBAction)btnShowClicked:(UIButton*)sender {

CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero tblObject];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tblObject indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];

MyCustomCell *customCell = [tblObject cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Comment: okay Mr. Dahiya,lemme try it, btw are you from susana,sisana etc lol ?
most dahiya's are from there

Comment: @ios_Dev hehehe I already made the same mistake, thats why I know what actually happening with you.

Comment: Kindly explain your NOTE: yes i want to use its object in other method

Comment: @ios_Dev I write the answer there, you just write these line in button action, nothing else to do .

Answer (score 0):

I know you have already resolved the issue. Still posting for someone who might need complete code. FYI, you can use the same method for both buttons, you can directly check in that method which button was clicked with `btn.tag` as button object is already passed.

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        customTableCell *customCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        [customCell.btn1 setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Button %ld",(long)indexPath.row]
     forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [customCell.btn2 setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Button %ld",(long)indexPath.row+10]
                         forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [customCell.btn1 setTag:indexPath.row];
        [customCell.btn2 setTag:indexPath.row+10];

        [customCell.btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [customCell.btn2 addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        return customCell;
    }
    -(void) btnClicked:(UIButton *) btn {
        UIAlertController *alertC = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Button %ld tapped",(long)btn.tag] preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        UIAlertAction *action = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:nil];
        [alertC addAction:action];
        [self presentViewController:alertC animated:true completion:nil];
    }

    -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
        return 1;
    }
    -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        return 5;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

I have create this redio button in **cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
btnper = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btnper.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 30);
btnper.tag = indexPath.row;
btnper.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0f];
[btnper setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Radiooff1"]
        forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnper setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnper setTitle:@" 0%" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnper addTarget:self action:@selector(btnperPress:)   
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.contentView addSubview:btnper];
```

this is my **Action Method** to identify which cell button is pressed

```
- (IBAction)btnperPress:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSInteger selectedCheckBox = sender.tag; 
    NSLog (@"%d",selectedCheckBox);
}
```

Comment: Not a proper solution as its create new button every time while new cell created.